# SSL_library_init() failure

Tags: ssl, openssl

In my code SSL library function `SSL_library_init()` is not returning 1 as expected.
How can I see what error does it return?

I called SSL_load_error_strings() after SSL_library_init() but not getting any idea as how to see the error codes/messages returned by SSL_library_init()?

Any hints or a demo code to see the usage of SSL_load_error_strings?

Comment: `SSL_library_init` does not fail. It always returns 1. See [Library Initialization](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Library_Initialization) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Answer (score 1):

If you look into the code of openssl `SSL_library_init` calls several functions and then returns 1. There is no other way out of this function except the return 1 so it should be impossible for the function to return anything else (like it is documented).

So please check your code that it really calls the `SSL_library_init` from openssl and not something else.

Comment: Well I just checked and see the return value of SSL_library_init() as 0.

Comment: @RupeshKumar, this is what he is talking about: https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/a898936218bc279b5d7cdf76d58a25e7a2d419cb/ssl/ssl_algs.c

Comment: @Rupesh Kumar - something else is going on. You need to provide more information. Perhaps you can set a breakpoint at `SSL_library_init`, and post the results of `bt full` before the function returns.

Answer (score 0):

> Any hints or a demo code to see the usage of SSL_load_error_strings?

See [Library Initialization](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Library_Initialization) on the OpenSSL wiki. From the wiki:

```
**Library Apps**

The following examines how the OpenSSL development team uses initialization in the OpenSSL utilities.

s_client initializes itself with the following calls:

    * OpenSSL_add_ssl_algorithms
    * SSL_load_error_strings 

s_server initializes itself with the following calls:

    * SSL_load_error_strings();
    * OpenSSL_add_ssl_algorithms(); 

s_time initializes itself with the following calls:

    * OpenSSL_add_ssl_algorithms(); 

state_machine initializes itself with the following calls:

    * SSL_library_init();
    * OpenSSL_add_ssl_algorithms();
    * SSL_load_error_strings();
    * ERR_load_crypto_strings();
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you including Perforce libs by any chance?
Perforce includes a p4sslstub.lib that overrides all imports with a 0 when linked against after the correct openssl library, which results in SSL_library_init() returning 0.